# LokiJS: when using DynamicView().branchResultSet with applySort it doesn't sort the collection

Tags: javascript, typescript, lokijs

I am having a problem getting data from a `branchResultSet` after using the `applySort` on the view. The reason I am using that is because I want a limit of 10 records back and not the whole thing for better performance. When I use only the data method it works as expected.

Example code:

```js
switch() {
  // ...
  case 'Name':
  // This code was added elsewhere. I added this as an example of how I
  // initialize the variable studentView.
  this.studentView = studentColl.addDynamicView('view');
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  this.studentsView.applySort((a: IStudent, b: IStudent) => {
    if (a.firstName.toLowerCase() < b.firstName.toLowerCase()) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.firstName.toLowerCase() > b.firstName.toLowerCase()) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }).applySort((a, b) => {
    if (a.lastName.toLowerCase() < b.lastName.toLowerCase()) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.lastName.toLowerCase() > b.lastName.toLowerCase()) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  break;
};

this.students = this.studentsView.branchResultset(lokiViews.viewPaging, { pageStart: 0, pageSize: 10 }).data();
//...
```

I expected to see collection sorted.

If I use `this.studentView.data()`, I see the data sorted as expected.

When I use `applyWhere` it works as expected.

Using the `branchResultSet` method also didn't work with `applySimpleSort(param)`.

`applyFind` also works as expected.

My only issues have been with both **Sort** methods.

I'm using StencilJS and TypeScript but I don't believe the issue is with those frameworks because I tried running similar code on a Vanilla HTML-JavaScript and had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying code (`Resultset.prototype.copy`) does not not perform the sort before branching.  You can do it though.

```
if (this.studentsView.sortDirty || this.studentsView.resultsdirty) {
    this.studentsView.performSortPhase({
        suppressRebuildEvent: true
    });
}
this.students = this.studentsView.branchResultset(lokiViews.viewPaging, { pageStart: 0, pageSize: 10 }).data();
```